# Java List Listener throws Null pointer error, despite being able to access array

Tags: java, if-statement, compare, awt

This is an listener for a list component. I get a null pointer error from when people select it, but I am still able to get the information I need from the array. The problem is the compiler still throws a null pointer event every time I click on the list item. How I am able to correctly access the array, while it still throws this error?
class facebookListListener implements ActionListener{

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            moodSetter.setEnabled(true);
            String name = thePeople[facebookList.getSelectedIndex()].getName();
            String mood = thePeople[facebookList.getSelectedIndex()].getMood();
            Color lightGrey = new Color(160,160,160);
            if(mood == null){
                thePersonsMood.setText("default_mood");
                thePersonsMood.setBackground(lightGrey);

            }
            if(mood.equalsIgnoreCase("happy")){
                thePersonsMood.setText(name+"'s mood is " + mood);
                thePersonsMood.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }else{
                thePersonsMood.setText(name+"'s mood is " + mood);
                thePersonsMood.setBackground(lightGrey);
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which line in the code above throws your NPE? Most importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). You should inspect the line carefully that throws it, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! An actually [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses.  Also, the compiler won't throw a NPE

Comment: It says 107, at if(mood.equalsIgnoreCase("happy")){]

Comment: @user3558462 I presume that now that you have that information, the problem is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, change this:

```
}
if(mood.equalsIgnoreCase("happy")){
```

to this:

```
} else // **** note the else!!!
if(mood.equalsIgnoreCase("happy")){
```

Otherwise you'll go into the if block even if the `if (mood == null)` test is true.